# N-triples to RDF/XML JavaScript converter for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rdf, n-triples

I am looking for a JavaScript N-triples to RDF/XML converter. Actually I will use it in NodeJS.

Does anybody know of a JavaScript library to convert N-triples into RDF/XML?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but maybe https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdf-raptor-node-js would do it; it wraps my Raptor rdf syntax library with a Node.js binding.  This is a compiled binding, not native JS.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, can't make raptor work.

So I designed a little web service that I call with node.js : http://semola-rdf.appspot.com
(with a HTTP POST endpoint)

There is a jquery plugin that could do this too (http://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/), but can't make jquery with node neither...